# Не удаётся запуск кода c# и любого проекта в Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, project

Почему то нету кнопки «создать проект» в VS Code. И не знаю как запустить код c#,в ютубе только старые версии vs code есть,все посмотрел,не нашел способа запустить код и проект в vs code. Запустил код c# и выводится **«[WARNING]: x86 Windows  is not supported  by the .NET debugger. Debugging will not be available»**.
Кстати у меня скачан расширение **"Code Runner"**.
Вот раздел "о программе" **(Нажал в кнопку "Справка",потом  в "О программе")**:

> Версия: 1.63.2 (user setup)
> Фиксация: 899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3
> Дата: 2021-12-15T09:53:24.645Z (2 нед. назад)
> Electron: 13.5.2
> Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
> Node.js: 14.16.0
> V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
> OC: Windows_NT ia32 61.7601

Comment: Вы под linux?..

Comment: x86 Windows is not supported by the .NET debugger. Debugging will not be available

Comment: aepot,нет,у меня виндовс 7, 32 бита

Comment: @Иван переустановите систему на x64, и проблема уйдет. Не вижу смысла сидеть на 32-битной системе в 2022 году, тем более, если вы разработчик. Советую даже сразу десятку поставить, конечно если оперативы больше 2 гигов имеется. Если всего 2 гига, то можно остаться на семере, если меньше, то вашему компу уже пора на пенсию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, ответ Вам выше уже дали, я просто немного расшифрую его не тему "что же делать".

Итак, 32-битные системы признаны устаревшими и не поддерживаются. Это позвоялет разработчикам экономить кучу усилий - уж Вы поверьте.

Теперь надо понять: у Вас 32 битная система из за ограничений аппаратуры или по нелепой случайности?

Если аппаратура (процессор, ноутбук, и т.п.) 64-разрядные (то есть, произведены в этом веке и не более 7-10 лет назад), и на них просто по недоразумению вкрячили Windows 32 bit - сносите её нафиг, и ставьте современную 64-разрядную ОС.

Обращу Ваше внимание на то, что у Windows 7 скоро закончится [срок поддержки Microsoft'ом](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-7). А потом будет так:  закончился срок поддержки - нет секьюрити фиксов и сервис паков - так может, пора уже того, закопать стюардессу?

Если же Вам не повезло, и Ваша аппаратура - 32 битная (то есть, если бы она была ребенком, она должна была бы уже заканчивать школу и получать паспорт), то у Вас опять таки, есть выход!

Вы можете вместо VS Code поставить нормальную (немного старую) Visual Studio - то есть, профессиональную среду разработки от MS, просто немного устаревшую (например, VS 2015 или даже VS 2019) - просто у таких VS и требования к аппаратуре довольно скромные, а возможности писать код на C# - не очень сильно уступают VS Code.

Правда, при этом Вы будете ограничены в версии языка - скорее всего, C# 7.0 (без хаков).

Более современные VS поддерживают более новый стандарт C#, но насчет их запуска в 32 битной винде - надо попробовать.

Успехов!

Comment: Нононо, семера еще живее всех живых. Правда немного ей осталось https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-7.

Comment: @aepot - я уберу "перебор", хотя я шутил, в основном, над самим собой

Comment: Насколько я помню, то на семеру можно вполне без проблем VS 2019 поставить, но могу ошибаться.

Answer (score 0):

```
x86 Windows is not supported by the .NET debugger. Debugging will not be available
```

Уже все написано что приложение не может выполнить отладку в x86 смотри зависимости